# Time-series Decay identification

Tags: time-series, matlab, seasonality, signal-processing

Are there any known techniques or methods to extract and identify decays from a time-series of data?

By "extract and identify" I mean finding similar features as those in the blue boxes in the figure.

[image: Time Series Data]

Comment: Pls define decay? It's the case that beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: If the decay patterns are of same length => seasonality; If the patterns are of different lengths => cycles